Conjecture: Two different random triangles (both based on random points on a circle) have the same distribution of side length ratios.
On a circle, choose three uniformly random points $A,B,C$.
Triangle $T_1$ has vertices $A,B,C$. The side lengths of $T_1$ are, in random order, $a,b,c$.
Triangle $T_2$ is formed by drawing tangents to the circle at $A,B,C$. ($T_2$ may or may not lie inside the circle.) The side lengths of $T_2$ are, in random order, $d,e,f$.

Is the following conjecture true:

The distribution of ratios of $a,b,c$ is the same as the distribution of ratios of $d,e,f$.

So for example, if my conjecture is true, then we would have the following probability equations:

$P(a^2+b^2<c^2)=P(d^2+e^2<f^2)$
$P(a^3+b^3<c^3)=P(d^3+e^3<f^3)$
$P(ab<c^2)=P(de<f^2)$
$P\left(\frac1a+\frac1b<\frac1c\right)=P\left(\frac1d+\frac1e<\frac1f\right)$

(My conjecture, if true, would not imply that $P(ab<c)=P(de<f)$, because these inequalities are not dimensionally homogeneous.)
Basis for my conjecture
I found that $P(ab<c^2)=\frac35$. Then I wondered what $P(de<f^2)$ equals, and a simulation suggests that it also equals $\frac35$.
I found that $P\left(\frac1a+\frac1b<\frac1c\right)=\frac15$. Then I wondered what $P\left(\frac1d+\frac1e<\frac1f\right)$ equals, and a simulation suggests that it also equals $\frac15$.
I tried some other probabilities, and simulations suggest that each probability has the same value for the two triangles.
So I suspect that the two triangles have the same distribution of ratios of side lengths. But I don't know why.

I think this is called a contact triangle

The angles in $T1$ are half the corresponding angles at the centre of the circle, so they are unuformly distributed on the triangle $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=\pi$.
The angles in $T2$ are either $\pi-2\alpha,\pi-2\beta,\pi-2\gamma$ or $2\alpha,2\beta,2\gamma-\pi$. I haven't worked out the details, but expect they are also uniformly distributed.

But what about the side lengths? I don't think the side lengths of $T_2$ are uniformly distributed. They can be arbitrarily large.

$T1$ and $T2$ are equally likely to be $1^\circ,29^\circ,150^\circ$, so are equally likely to have that specific ratio of lengths.

I don't think the central angles are uniformly distributed. Let $\theta$ be a central angle. $P(0^\circ<\theta<1^\circ)$ is much greater than $P(359^\circ<\theta<360^\circ)$.

I mean evenly spread on the triangle with vertices $(360^\circ,0^\circ,0^\circ),(0^\circ,360^\circ,0^\circ),(0^\circ,0^\circ,360^\circ)$

That is, for example $32^\circ,146^\circ,182^\circ$ is just as likely as $61^\circ,200^\circ,99^\circ$
